# Can I do topic classification of Arabic text (software requirements) without a training dataset?

Tags: classification, algorithm-request

I am trying to make a text classification for Arabic data. The problem is that there is no labeled Arabic dataset for this data. My question is then: is possible to do a classification without a training dataset? If yes, what methods can I use?

Comment: Hi. It's not clear to me why you have "software requirements"  in the title. Can you clarify that?

Comment: the data that I want to classify is a software requirements

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to do it. This can be posed as an unsupervised text classification. You can look at TF-IDF, Neural networks ([BERT](https://github.com/alisafaya/Arabic-BERT)) etc. for creating embedding of your text and then, use clustering techniques like K-Means, KNN etc. for classification.

Comment: as i know  unsupervised text classification needs an unlabeled dataset which I don't have

Comment: if you even don't have data, how do you expect to create a model. unsupervised is albeit a safety net when supervised is not possible. no data = no model. anyways, the BERT link is for Arabic language, maybe use that to do it directly but that would still need data.

Comment: https://lionbridge.ai/datasets/best-arabic-datasets-for-machine-learning/ and you do have datasets. or you need to create a small dataset yourself. but dataset is a precondition for a model.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)